# jquery - target label with no adjacent "select" input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the labelsFX plugin to turn label text into text in input fields which fade out on focus. This is fine apart from the fact that select dropdown boxes break if i try to apply the effect to the adjacent label. So I only want to apply this effect where the label is adjacent to a text or textarea input field.

So what I want to do is something like this, but it's clearly not right - anyone know how to fix this?

```
$('label').next('not:(select)').labelsFX();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```
$("label + input, label + textarea").prev()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/8Kxnb/1/

Comment: Yup, you've nailed it :) Cheers @Xeon06 - haven't seen that syntax before, very handy

Answer (score 0):

You could select all the textfields using the following selector:

```
$("input[type='text']")
```

Answer (score -1):

try this syntax:

```
$('input, textarea').labelsFx();
```